# How to load missing firmware to the install media

Tags: software-installation

For a clean install of 14.04, I get the message "b43-open/ucode5.fw" not found. I look in the installation guide section about "how to load missing firmware" but could not get an answer--all the answer seem to assume that you have a terminal. My question is how to prepare install media with the missing firmware.  I have downloaded the install and made a dvd which I can learn about ubuntu but the installation hang at the point where it says configuring bcmwla kernel source or some such.  Can I do it on another machine, I have another with Mint 17, no trouble with that install, it use Realtek wlan.

Comment: Please read here and see if that helps: http://askubuntu.com/questions/55868/installing-broadcom-wireless-drivers

Answer (score 0):

"Insert your device into your computer containing the installation ISO of Ubuntu (Whether CD, DVD, USB stick or whatever), wait for appearance of this screen

and Immediately press a button. Choose the language of the installer and press enter. You will see something similar to this:

at this point position yourself to "Try Ubuntu without installing" or "Install Ubuntu" (Is irrelevant) but DO NOT PRESS ENTER: instead the press F6, Immediately followed by the ESC key: You should be able to write in a textbox. Now go (in the textbox) more to the right that can, leave intact the existing text and write, Appended to it (and being careful that after the two dashes there is a space), the string

b43.blacklist=yes

after that press Sending.

system installation will start and will not hang over!"

http://linux-software-news-tutorials.blogspot.com/2012/04/installing-ubuntu-1204-crashes-because.html

and

http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1966631